# Apache virtualhosts still redirect to /var/www

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I am trying to link 4 domain names to one server, though I have never worked with Apache's virtual hosts, I figured I'd give it a try.

What I did is the following:

I created 4 `.conf` files, one for each domain name (example.com.conf, example.eu.conf). These are all loaded with configurations similar to this one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.nl
        ServerName  www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
    # Indexes + Directory Root.
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /home/www/www.example.com/htdocs/

    # CGI Directory
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/www/www.example.com/cgi-bin/
    <Location /cgi-bin>
            Options +ExecCGI
    </Location>


    # Logfiles
    ErrorLog  /home/www/www.example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /home/www/www.example.com/logs/access.log combined
```

After that I used the `a2ensite` command to enable all the websites and I restarted apache.

The domain names all have a single A record pointed to my servers IPv4.

However, after all this configuring, whenever I visit one of the domains, these still show me the default Apache launch page (/var/www/) instead of their individual indexes. I've made sure the domains are all mentioned in my `hosts` file too.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you place this .conf files? Did you check the main .conf file, maybe you have them defined there also, or maybe you conf files aren't included in IncludeOptional. Show you apache2.conf with  grep -ve \# -ve '^$' apache2.conf

Comment: Use `apache2ctl -S` to dump the vhost config as apache sees it.